# Picture In Picture - Software recommendation

Tags: software-recommendation

Preferably free ones, but I'm willing to shell out some cash if it's well worth its value.

I have a very limited video editing experience but I'm willing to learn, so here is the criteria that I'm looking for :

- Picture In Picture feature (multiple videos side by side; no limit in max videos)
- Easy learning curve - or at least has a large community base so tutorials are vast
- Able to put audio in (I mean, what video editor can't anyway? Haha)

I'm going to be using it to make videos of me playing multiple instruments, so if there are any other things that I need to know about videos that I might not be seeing now, feel free to let me know with your answers.